# What is the minimum/suggested sequence length for training an LSTM?

Tags: deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I want to train an LSTM but my sequences' length are on average around 4/5 time steps. 
What are the suggested sequence length? 
May 4/5 time steps be enough?

P.S. could you please post some link to scientific articles to endorse your claims?

Comment: why don't you try and see.  at worst it memorizes since the sequence length is not sufficiently long.

Comment: @user18764 before trying I wanted to know if there were some works already done